# laravel ajax on shared hosting

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a laravel application which is deployed on my server.

File structure

```
server
│

└───blog-app
│    │   app
│    │   bootstrap 
│    │   ......
│
└───public_html
    │    blog
    │     │─── index.php
    │
```

This is what my structure looks like. Up until now everything seemed to work fine, however now I was trying to make an AJAX call to my controller function but it doesn't work as it should have.

Let me explain it by an example,

```
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'{{route('blog.prefetchResults')}}',
     data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
     success:function(data){
              $("#msg").html(data.msg);
           }
     });
```

This is my ajax call which goes to the route `blog.prefetchResults` which points it to a controller that resides in the `BlogController`. However when I look in the browser console I see this kind of error:

> http://mysubdomain.com/blog/prefetchBlogController@prefetchResults 500 (Internal Server Error)

What I can infer from this error is that it does not allow me to access those directories when a client side request is made, this makes me ask a very simple question: How am I supposed to make an AJAX request using laravel if I can't do it this way?

Update(EXample):

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

**test.blade.php**

```
@extends('main')
<p>
This is an ajxax test
</p>
<button class="butt">
    click me
</button>
<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        $('butt').on('click',function(){
                $.ajax({
                 type:'GET',
                 url:'{{route('blog.test')}}',
                 success:function(data){
                          $("p").html("somthing");
                       }
                 });
        })
    });
</script>
```

**Web.php**

```
//Test controller
Route::get('blog/test'.'BlogController@test')->name('blog.test');
```

**BlogController**

```
 public function test(){
       return view('test.test')->withMessage('changed');
    }
```

**File structure**

File structure

```
 server
    │

    └───blog-app //Not accessible through client side languages 
    │    │   app->Http->Controllers/BlogController.php
    │    │   resources->views->test->test.blade.php
    │    │  routes->web.php->route defined here
    │
    └───public_html(www folder)// accessible to the client (www.mydomain.com)
        │    blog
        │     │─── index.php
        │
```

**@Alejandro Reply**

- corrected the above problems.
- Sorry about `app->Http->BlogController.php` ,it's `app->Http->Controllers/BlogController.php`.

**Note:**

- The public_html directory is the root directory, that is the root point for my `mydomain.com`.
- So the other folders such as `blog-app` is not accessible for the normal users,they can be only accessed by server side languages.

**Log File**

```
[2017-01-08 19:23:01] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 
'Trying to get property of non-object' in 
/home/mydomainuser/blogapp/storage/framework/views/af6b0045a9d30a80c19dd552032d46b39ad1cc99.php:1



Next exception 'ErrorException' with message 
'Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/foodq7y4/blogapp/resources/views/blog/single.blade.php)' in 
/home/mydomainuser/blogapp/storage/framework/views/af6b0045a9d30a80c19dd552032d46b39ad1cc99.php:1
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**Single.blade.php**

```
 @extends('main')

@section('title', '| Blog')

@section('content')


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1>Blog</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h2>{{ ucwords($post->title) }}</h2>
            <h5>Published: {{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</h5>

            <p>{{ substr(strip_tags($post->body), 0, 250) }}{{ strlen(strip_tags($post->body)) > 250 ? '...' : "" }}</p>

            <a href="{{ route('blog.single', $post->slug) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Read More</a>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-center">
                {!! $posts->links() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


@endsection
```

Comment: Try and use the actual path of the url and not the route

Comment: it wont work either cause that directory is only accessible to the server side

Comment: client is only allowed the inside of the public_html

Comment: Have you tried `url("blog/prefetchResults");` instead of your `route` method? The url one creates a fully qualified url.

Comment: Also, have you setup the transfer of your CSRF token?

Comment: I don't think it's a safe inference that a 500 error is related to AJAX, I'd expect a 401 if your JS was unauthorized to access that URL. Do you have a good reason to think otherwise? Also, I'm assuming based on your error that your JS *is* being reprocessed, but to eliminate the assumption I'd like to point out that JS generally isn't processed by PHP so doing things like `<?php echo csrf_token() ?>'` generally won't work. Can you confirm (and preferably [edit] with post processed content) that your JS is what you expect?

Comment: yes i did , that wont work cause it would be something like this `mydomain.com/blog/prefetchResults` and it doesnt exist , because the files lies above the public_html

Comment: sure , let me put everything with a good examplee

Comment: Well, as I understand from your question, the domain (abc.com) is routed on the whole public_html folder, not on the public folder of your laravel app. So, for various reasons (security is the most important), other ppl should not have access to the folders and files, especially the `.env` file. That's why you should route a domain to the `public_html/blog/public` folder. The AJAX problem should be solved then too.

Comment: Have you checked `.htaccess`(if any) file within the public directory which routes everything to your front controller or `index.php`. And make sure that the `mod_rewrite` is enabled in the server and configured properly.

Comment: @manniL yes it is configured on the public html folder and no one has access outside it and all the cconfig files are outside the public_html

Comment: @code-jaff everything is fine

Comment: Looks like the error is in your `resources/views/blog/single.blade.php` view.  What is the content of that view?

Comment: @EricTucker i have updated the question and i have kind of figured the solution, it was because it has a `post->link` there and i didn't use `paginate` before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried accessing the url directly with your browser?
Given that you are getting "500 (Internal Server Error)" I'd begin by inspecting the server logs.
Some things, however:

- You should be calling the element class: `$('.butt')`, but I guess you got that.
- You don't need to pass the csrf token for a GET request. Unless you want to do some validation/authorization of your own. For POST requests, Laravel will check the token. You can send it in the HTTP headers with an ajax option `headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'}`.
- If you want to send the data as a plain string, remove the spaces: `data:'_token=<?php echo csrf_token() ?>'`, otherwise the field ends up being set as `_token_`.
- However, I think it's better to set the request data as a JS object: `{'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'}`
- You said your file structure has `app->Http->BlogController.php`. By default Laravel expects the controllers to be in `app/Http/Controllers` directory.
- It looks like the controller returns an html string, so `data.msg` probably returns `undefined`. Instead, `data` is the html string.

Try fixing these things, then comment or edit with follow-up.

---

Update:
From the server logs we found out the problem was in `views/blog/single.blade.php`. You already figured out it was `$posts->links` and apparently posts was not an object.

Comment: I have updated my question with the log file content, hope this helps

Comment: @BOTJr. ok, it looks like some object is null in view `blog.single`. You may post that if you want so we can take a look

Comment: i have updated my question and i have figured the problem as well, if you want you can update the answer and i will select the answer as correct :) . I dont wanna answer myself.You have put up a lot of effort! 


it was because it has a post->link there and i didn't use paginate before.

Answer (score 0):

When doing AJAX requests, remember to always return JSON responses using the `response()->json()` method instead of using views like in your `BlogController test()` method example.

Also, implement something like [LogViewer](https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LogViewer) in your admin panel (if you have any) to see the log file(s) and read the errors that occur. Setting up [Bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com/) is not a bad idea either.

Comment: let me upload the log file content as well

Comment: Some object is null, that's why you are getting that error in the view but as I said, you shouldn't return a view when using AJAX requests, only JSON responses are valid.

Answer (score 0):

In application this is working great. Change your code like this:

1.View part

```
<p id="response"></p>
        <button class="butt">
            click me
        </button>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.butt').on('click',function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType:'HTML',
                        type:'GET',
                        url:'{{route('blog.test')}}',
                        success:function(data){
                            $("#response").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
```

2.Controller part

```
    public function test()
    {
        return \View::make('test.test')->withMessage('changed');
        //or  return view()->withMessage('changed');
    }
```

And for feature open console click on network after that when you will click on button it will show you red link if there is an error

1. Click on that link
2. In the tab list on the top of console find preview (And Server side error will be shown to you).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript

Sending HTTP requests to the actual routes instead of the named routes worked for me.

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('.butt').on('click',function(){
            $.ajax({
               method: 'GET',
               dataType:'json',
               url:'/blog/test',
               success: function(data){
                  console.log(typeof(data)) // see Object {}
               }
            });
    })
});
```

BlogController

A JSON response should be generated for AJAX requests.

```
public function test(){
   return response()
        ->json(['type' => 'Test', 'message' => 'It works!']);
}
```

CSRF Protection

Many options here. My personal favorite:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```